# Red5 1.0.6 Release startup error: Could not resolve placeholder rtmp.executor.core_pool_size

Tags: java, red5

I'm trying to install 1.0.6 release on a second Windows 2008 server.  The first install was fine but I'm getting an error when I try to start Red5 on the second server.

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix it?

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:123)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'red5.core' defined in class path resource [red5.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'messageExecutor' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.executor.core_pool_size' in string value "${rtmp.executor.core_pool_size}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.executor.core_pool_size' in string value "${rtmp.executor.core_pool_size}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:69)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'messageExecutor' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.executor.core_pool_size' in string value "${rtmp.executor.core_pool_size}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.executor.core_pool_size' in string value "${rtmp.executor.core_pool_size}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.refresh(Red5ApplicationContext.java:36)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:151)
    at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(Red5ApplicationContext.java:30)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.executor.core_pool_size' in string value "${rtmp.executor.core_pool_size}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what happened but I just deleted the entire Red5 directory and copied the contents of the Red5 zip back to the Red5 directory and everything worked again.

Comment: My guess is that the red5.properties file was missing in the first run.